# Find the number of bits in sage for a number

Tags: sage

Is there any way that I can get the number of bits for a number inside the sage? `.binary()` command just displays bits for a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nbits`, which stands for "number of bits":

`sage: a = 123456789
sage: a.nbits()
27`

This will be faster and use less memory than actually computing the bits and getting their length.  You can also do `a.ndigits()` for the number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have got the answer and I post it here, maybe it will help someone later:

```
sage: a = 123456789
sage: v = a.digits(2)
sage: len(v)
27
```